# assigning the same number to similar rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis

I have a square matrix of dimension N. I want to define a vector of size N that has as first component:
all row indices of the rows of the matrix which are the same as the first row.
and as second component:
all row indices of the rows of the matrix which are the same as the second row.

and so on.

I am working on R and I have been trying to do that for some time now. Any idea on how to proceed would me much appreciated.

```
myMatrix <- matrix(rep(1:4, 4), ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    4    4
[5,]    1    1
[6,]    2    2
[7,]    3    3
[8,]    4    4
```

What I have tried :

```
res <- list(NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
  row_selected <- myMatrix[i,]
    res[[i]] <- which(myMatrix[i,]==row_selected)
}

res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr` version:

```
# turn the matrix into a dataframe
myDf <- myMatrix %>% as.data.frame()

myDf %>% # and now get a left join of ...
    left_join(
        myDf %>% # ...the same dataframe with the index you were looking for
            distinct_all() %>%
            mutate(index = 1:nrow(.)))
```

Comment: Thank you ! I am not used to using the package dplyr. Seems like a nice package to deal with dataframes !

Comment: Welcome. You can get more information on how to use `dplyr` as a part of the "`tidyverse`" at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ It's the online version of a very good book.